# is there any limitation for ipa file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, adhoc

i am trying to syink 300MB ipa file to test my app through itunes but it is not loading total 300MB.it is loading upto 200MB. so my doubt here is any limitation have for ipa.i searched many links but it wont work for me.please tell me.
Thank you all,
ajay

Comment: can you explain what happens? we have a 25mb ipa file that works fine, but haven't tried any larger yet.

Comment: Does the device have enough room? 
Apps like Epic Citadel are in the 700Mb range so those sizes are supported.

Comment: my app ipa is 278.2MB which contains seven books and some images like thumbnails,audio files,video files etc.i am getting only five books through the ipa.while the app running through building works well i am getting all Books and files(278.2MB).

Comment: Is this happening during an ad-hoc distribution?  Why are you trying to install an .ipa file through iTunes?  Why not just let Xcode install the built application for you?

Comment: we are trying to show my app to the client.

Comment: the device which i am using for beta testing which is in the ad-hoc distribution.i am using two devices in both the devices facing same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Check that all the books are included in your distribution/adhoc target too.

Copy the ipa file. Change the extension to .zip and extract. Find your .app file then right click and select show package contents. Verify that everything is there.

If there are files missing then expand the Target node in Xcode project and check they are included for your distribution build.

Comment: Thanks Koregan ,i already tested..No files aren't missed, i didn't understand this line "Check that all the books are included in your distribution/adhoc target too."

Comment: @user568065 - There is the possibility that certain resources are only being built into your debug / testing target and not your ad hoc / distribution one.  Inspect a file and go to the Targets tab in the inspector.  Make sure that your ad hoc target is checked for each of these book resources.  Also, look inside the bundle of your compiled ad hoc application to make sure they really are ending up in the application bundle.